# Why is the definition of the dual sheaf is independent of the ambient space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space

I'm reading "The Geometry of Moduli Space of Sheaves" (Huybrechts,Lehn). He gives a new definition of the dual sheaf:
$\ $Let E be a coherent sheaf of dimension $d$ ,and let $c=n-d$ be its codimension.The dual sheafis defined as:
$$E^D=\mathcal{Ext}_{X}^{c}(E,\omega_{X})$$

It is then stated that this definition of the dual has the advantage of being independent of the ambient space

Namely if $X,Y$ are smooth, $i:X \rightarrow Y$ is a closed embedding, then:
$$(i_{*}E)^D=i_{*}(E^D)$$
Can you give some advice to prove this equality? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What you need is called Grothendieck duality.

Comment: Thanks，maybe I can solve it with exercise 3.6.10(b) and lemma 3.7.4 in Hartshorne's book